# Prove that a maximum degree of vertex is greater than or equal than $12$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a graph of $25$ vertices; when I pick any three vertices at least two are adjacent. Prove that a maximum degree of vertex of this graph is greater than or equal than $12$.

I am having trouble starting with this problem.. if anyone can help grateful in advance!

Comment: Sometimes it pays off to look at parts of the graph that have extremal properties. Assume all vertices have degree $\leq 11$. Let $v_0$ be a vertex with maximum degree, and $A$ its set of neighbors. Since $|A|\leq 11$, the set of vertices $B$ not in  $A\cup\{v_0\}$ has cardinality at least $13$. Take from $B$ a vertex $v_1$ that has a maximum number of neighbors in $A$. Note that even if $v_1$ has no neighbors in $A$, since its degree is $\leq 11$, by assumption, there is a vertex $v_2\in B$ that is not a neighbor of $v_1$. Then $\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ don't have edges between them.

Comment: Another common strategy used in this argument is that in graph theory you can often give a proof that consists of an algorithm that searches for the solution. The proof consisting in showing that the algorithm terminates on a solution. In this case, it was searching for an independent set of three vertices, under the assumption that all degrees are $\leq 11$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution has already been given in the comments. Here's a different one that utilizes Mantel's Theorem. The theorem asserts that a triangle-free graph $G$ on $n$ vertices has at most $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges. You can find its (relatively simple) proof online.

Now if we denote our graph by $G$ then it's easy to see that its complement, $\overline{G}$, is triangle-free. By Mantel's theorem we have $m(\overline{G}) \leq \frac{25^2}{4} < 157$. But remember that $m(\overline{G})=\binom{25}{2}-m(G)$ so
$$\boxed{m(G) > \binom{25}{2}-157 = 143}$$

Now if the maximum degree of $G$ was less than $11$ we would have $\deg u \leq 11$ for all vertices $u$ and the handshaking lemma would give
$$\boxed{m(G) \leq \frac{11}{2}\cdot n(G) = \frac{11\cdot 25}{2} < 138}$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore the maximum degree of $G$ is greater than or equal to $12$.